# Conceptual doubt in finding the range of values in this question

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to find The set of values of $\lambda$ such that $\tan^2\theta+\sec\theta=\lambda$

By forming a quadratic in sec and using the quadratic equation I get
$$\sec\theta=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt(5+4\lambda)}{2}$$

Now applying range conditions for sec I get two inequalities

$\lambda\geq1$ and $\lambda\geq-1$

But the answer is only $\lambda\geq1$

I'm not able do understand why lambda can't have values in between -1 and 1 as it is also a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of values of $\theta$ in your problem is probably restricted to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Otherwise for example if $\theta=\pi$ your function is equal to $-1$. Assuming that, the values of the secant are in $[1,\infty)$. In terms of the secant, your LHS is
$$
\sec^2\theta+\sec\theta-1
$$
a quadratic function of $\sec\theta$. This quadratic function $t\to g(t)= t^2+t-1$ is increasing on $(-1/2,+\infty)$. Therefore the image of $[1,\infty)$ is $[g(1),\infty)=[1,\infty)$.